# The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have two amazon instances, I have uploaaded the same war in both instances, In one instance it is running properly(giving expected result) but in another instance it is giving the following error

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Example-RS] threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Root Cause
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2283)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1260)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:700)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:678)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I google regarding this error, I got suggestion related to `web.xml` file, If it related to `web.xml` file then it should not be executed in another instance as well

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is an [`IncompatibleClassChangeError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IncompatibleClassChangeError.html). According to the documentation, this error is

> Thrown when an incompatible class change has occurred to some class definition. The definition of some class, on which the currently executing method depends, has since changed.

Double check the version of your application server and the versions of all libraries and classes located outside the war file.